# Generating SWIG wrapper to C++ function pointers in C#

Tags: c#, c++, swig

I am very new to SWIG and don't have much experience in C++ in general. I'm having trouble understanding how to generate a C# program that can call into a C++ dll using SWIG. I've looked through a lot of examples and forum posts, but it all seems to be beyond me. Please can somebody explain to me what is needed and what I'm doing wrong in a simple way?

I have a C++ dll with header files, only containing the typedef function pointer definitions, and I know the exported function names.

for example

```
/* example.h */
typedef int (*pointer_add) (const long date, const long noDays, long& result);
```

I just want to have a simple method call possible, in C# I would do this:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate int pointer_add(long date, long noDays, ref long po_res);

public pointer_add addDays { get; protected set; }

// get delegate for function pointer
IntPtr p = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(libraryHandle, "functionName");
Delegate function = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(p,typeof(pointer_add));
addDays = (pointer_add)function;

// invoke delegate 
addDays(date, noDays, out date);
```

but I need to go about this in a dynamic way so SWIG is the tool of choice, although I don't understand how it's all supposed to fit together...

```
/* interface.i */
%module wrapper
%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%define %cs_callback(TYPE, CSTYPE)
%typemap(ctype) TYPE, TYPE& "void*"
%typemap(in) TYPE  %{ $1 = ($1_type)$input; %}
%typemap(in) TYPE& %{ $1 = ($1_type)&$input; %}
%typemap(imtype, out="IntPtr") TYPE, TYPE& "CSTYPE"
%typemap(cstype, out="IntPtr") TYPE, TYPE& "CSTYPE"
%typemap(csin) TYPE, TYPE& "$csinput"
%enddef

%cs_callback(pointer_addDays, AddDays)
// int AddDays(pointer_addDays c); 

%include "example.h"

// swig -csharp -c++ interface.i
```

I am expecting all the magic to be found in the resulting interface_wrap.cxx file? With the AddDays line commented out of the interface.i file, I can't find anything relating to AddDays. If I uncomment `int AddDays(pointer_addDays c);` (which is not found in the original .h file) then I can see generated in the file:

```
SWIGEXPORT int SWIGSTDCALL CSharp_addDays(void* jarg1) {
  int jresult ;
  pointer_addDays arg1 ;
  int result;

  arg1 = (pointer_addDays)jarg1; 
  result = (int)addDays(arg1); // compiler error - identifier "addDays" is undefined!
  jresult = result; 
  return jresult;
}
```

and also I can see added in the wrapperPINVOKE.cs file:

```
  [global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("wrapper", EntryPoint="CSharp_addDays")]
  public static extern int addDays(AddDays jarg1);
```

Am I along the right lines here at all? Please could somebody advise what I am doing wrong to get the errors in the wrap.cxx file and what the next steps are?

Comment: Your example.h just has a typedef, but for your SWIG interface it's how you want things of that type to cross the language boundary that matters. Do you just have a global variable in your C++, or is it an argument that gets passed into functions too? Do you just implement it in C++ or does C# code need yo be passed in?

Comment: @Flexo I don't have access to the C++ source, only the headers. I am not sure what you mean by having a global variable in the C++ but from what I can see the typedefs are not passed around as an argument. The functions are be implemented in the C++ source, this is what I am trying to call, I don't need to pass in any C# code. In some cases, one function call would return an object and I would need to pass this reference into another function. I guess this is what the "IntPtr" typemap is for, to deal with this on the C# side?

Comment: If they're implemented in C++ and all you want to do is call them then how do you find them to call them?

Comment: I know that there is a convention used where if there is `typedef int (*pointer_add) (const long date, const long noDays, long& result);` defined  in the .h files then there will be an exported function `int add(const long date, const long noDays, long& result)` in the dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error I think I have managed to get this working.

The code/typemaps with `%define %cs_callback(TYPE, CSTYPE)` were not needed to simply call the functions that I was trying to get at. The functions were not included in the .h files but because I knew their naming convention I could add them myself.

For all the typedefs I had I changed them into a function signature in the interface .i file:

```
%module test
%{
#include "example.h"
%}

// all typedefs converted to functions by convention e.g. 
int addDays(const long date, const long noDays, long& result);
```

Since these functions were not included in the headers (which need to be added to the resulting C++/CLI wrapper project), I also had to make my own header file `exportedFunctions.h`

```
// exportedFunctions.h
namespace NamespaceUsedInCPlusPlusCode
{
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int addDays(const long date, const long noDays, long& result);
}
```

and include this in the SWIG-generated .cpp 
file so that it could find the functions and compile.

```
// interface_wrap.cxx
#include "exportedFunctions.h"
```

This meant that the addDays function was both wrapped by SWIG and found in the generated .cxx code, and let me compile the SWIG-generated code.